# % in input parameters of postman

Tags: regex, spring-boot, postman, query-string, get-request

In my postman GET request when i give this /agency?unitCode=%%%%%%%,

There is a regular expression to restrict the unitCode parameter to 2 digit alphanumeric
regexp: "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,2}$".

All other special characters are being properly recognized but when I give % , it doesnt work as expected and instead of giving bad request , gives me a proper answer.

while debugging, its showing that unitCode in this case is received as empty so does postman remove %.

Answer (score 0):

The percent sign in URL's is for encoding non-valid URL characters.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

If you were to send that query as percentage signs as intended, it would look like this:

`/agency?unitCode=%25%25%25%25%25%25%25`

Because your regex is allowing zero results (`{0,2}`) it's hitting that as valid. Is there a reason you're not matching `{1,2}` to ensure a result?